# `Manipulate` updating when it should not

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic

I have a `Manipulate[ListPlot[data[[m;;n]],{m,1,10},{n,1,10}]`. I execute, the plot is shown, I save the notebook, close Mathematica. I run Mathematica again, start executing code that is completely unrelated and I get thrown errors in Manipulate because at that point the list `data` is not existing. I even tried to use `TrackedSymbols :> {m, n}` without any help, as soon as I execute anything in the notebook after opening, `Manipulate` tries to update the plot, which is clearly not wanted.

Is there a way to get around this? It is incredibly annoying, especially when you do `Manipulate[ListPlot[{data[[m;;n]],data2[[m;;n]]},{m,1,30000},{n,1,30000}]` and at one point `data` exists and `data2` does not, then this line will print the whole, unabbreviated content of `data`, that is the dimension of `{30000,2}` and Mathematica front-end slows to a crawl.

Btw. this even looks like a bug (I am on 13.2.1 Linux).

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

data = RandomReal[10, {3, 20, 2}];
```

If you are going to plot a span of data, I recommend that you use an [`IntervalSlider`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalSlider.html)

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Evaluate[#[[int[[1]] ;; int[[2]]]] & /@ data],
  PlotRange -> MinMax /@ Transpose[Join @@ data],
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
  PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers",
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 {{int, {1, Length@data[[1]]}, "interval"}, 1, Length@data[[1]], 1,
  ControlType -> IntervalSlider,
  Method -> "Push",
  MinIntervalSize -> 5,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {int}]
```

[image]